# Change strings using script

Tags: php

I am on a site where I am looking for replacing 2 strings with each other.

I have 2 strings called **Cart** and **Bag**. I want to change where it is **Cart**, it'll be replaced with **Bag** and where it is **Bag**, it'll be replaced with **Cart**.

I have used the below PHP code to change strings:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function ( $strings ) {
    $text = array(
        'Bag' => 'Cart',
        'Cart' => 'Bag',
    );
    $strings = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $strings );
    return $strings;
}, 20 );
```

Which as a result shows al the **Cart** and **Bag** strings as **Bag**.

Can anyone please guide me what correction can be done here?

Or any script that can help?

TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take an example of `$strings`.

```
Bag Cart Cart Bag
```

`str_ireplace` searches the gives needles one by one and replaces them with the respective value from the replacements array (passed as the 2nd parameter) .

So, in this process, the string becomes,

```
1 --> Cart Cart Cart Cart
2 --> Bag  Bag  Bag  Bag
```

Although there are multiple ways to solve this issue, I would prefer the below approach.

- Explode the string based on space.
- Use array_map to map each value from the exploded array with regards to value from `$text`.
- Implode the array back to the string.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$strings = implode(" ", array_map(fn($v) => $text[$v] ?? $v, explode(" ", $strings)));
```

[`Online Demo`](https://3v4l.org/Lstp0)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into an array then replace cart with bag and vice-versa, and join the array again.

```js
const str = "This is a cart and bag, cart is cart and bag is bag"
let arr = str.split(" ");
let r = arr.map((s) => s.includes('cart') ? s.replace('cart', 'bag') : s.includes('bag') ? s.replace('bag', 'cart') : s)

let ans = r.join(" ")
console.log(ans)
```

Comment: Hello Yash, actually both phrases are not in a same string. They are in different places.

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: There is a string called "Move to Cart" and there is another string called "Add to Bag". I need to change that to "Move to Bag" and "Add to Cart". Something like this.

Comment: @Jituu And why do you think our answers won't work? Do you know basic programming? These examples should anyway be added to your question, especially when you say _Which as a result shows al the Cart and Bag strings as Bag._

Comment: Yes, I am also not dumb in programming. But this is just an example and there are a lot such strings. Also, your code breaks the site entirely. I found a solution to that though with my own code. Thanks.

Comment: @Jituu You have to learn how to use this site first. You said _Also, your code breaks the site entirely_ . I see this as an impossible thing! You haven't provided any minimum reproducible examples to the issue you are facing when using our answers yet making such baseless claims. You have to seriously refer to this [`SO doc`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).